# Certificate validation with ansible's maven_artifact

Tags: ansible, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to pull a jar from a Nexus that is using a self signed certificate.

```
ansible -m maven_artifact -a "repository_url=https://<nexus_host>/repository/maven-snampshots group_id=<group_id> artifact_id=<artifact_id> dest=/tmp/jars validate_certs=yes username=admin password=admin123" -i inventory.ini env_dev
```

I'm getting the following error :

> "msg": "Failed to validate the SSL certificate for XXXXXX. Make sure
>   your managed systems have a valid CA certificate installed. If the
>   website serving the url uses SNI you need python >= 2.7.9 on your
>   managed machine  (the python executable used (/usr/bin/python) is
>   version: 2.6 (r26:66714, May  6 2011, 15:10:21) [GCC 4.3.4
>   [gcc-4_3-branch revision 152973]]) or you can install the `urllib3`,
>   `pyOpenSSL`, `ndg-httpsclient`, and `pyasn1` python modules to perform
>   SNI verification in python >= 2.6. You can use validate_certs=False if
>   you do not need to confirm the servers identity but this is unsafe and
>   not recommended. Paths checked for this platform: /etc/ssl/certs,
>   /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem, /etc/pki/tls/certs,
>   /usr/share/ca-certificates/cacert.org, /etc/ansible. The exception msg
>   was: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:482: error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed."

Chrome let me download the certificate (.cer) from the Nexus server. But I don't know where do I need to install it. And How.

```
Nexus : OSS 3.14.0-04
Server Ansible : CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810
Client Ansible : SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)
```

Comment: Hey, why not using `validate_certs=False`? You have a old python version, so is the best option

Answer (score 0):

The way we get certs is by using openssl and pointing it at the site in question, downloading it as .pem, then installing that .pem onto the server making the calls or being called.

Get Cert:

```
openssl s_client -connect  site.com:636 </dev/null 2>/dev/null  | openssl x509 -outform PEM > site.pem
```

Import cert into CAcerts:

```
sudo keytool -importcert -noprompt -alias site-`date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S"` -file ./site.pem -keystore /usr/java/latest/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit
```